# In Sharepoint is there a way to restore a version with the original Modified By and Date?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

Asking for a friend who "somehow" saved something he shouldn't have.  We had explicit instructions that a word doc considered The Bible for our project that was last saved on April 1st wasn't to be touched.  People grew to see that "Modified" date of "April 1" and the Modified By of "Alex Brown" (spoiler alert: not the real name) as the date the Bible was last revised.

The friend (let's call him "Charles Davis") claims he opened the file, but didn't change anything and didn't hit save, and autosave was not enabled.  Unfortunately, it looks like somehow he saved the file, and the file's Modified Date says "45 Minutes Ago", the Modified by says "Charles Davis", and it's now Version 10.0 instead of Version 9.0.

I always though Version control would let us roll back to Version 9.0, which would restore the file to Version 9.0, the Modified Date to "April 1" and the Modified by to "Alex Brown".  However, attempting to roll back has just generated Version 11.0, with "Charles Davis" and "1 Minute ago".

The file size of Version 11.0 **DOES** match the file size of Version 9.0, so it does look like the rollback was successful.  However, "Alex Brown" and a lot of other people are going to be perturbed that they no longer see their "April 1" date.

Is there any way to get a true rollback to version 9.0 with the April 1 date and "Alex Brown" name?  Or are we stuck?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no out-of-box method to turn the version back to 9.0, this is by-design.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design in SharePoint. Whenever you restore the older version, it creates a new version with the content from older version.

Here's note from Microsoft official documentation:

> **Note**:  SharePoint doesn't remove the earlier version you just restored. It creates a copy and makes it the latest version.

**Source**: [Restore a previous version of an item or file in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/restore-a-previous-version-of-an-item-or-file-in-sharepoint-f66dbda0-81f4-4d1e-b08c-793265c58934)

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the system columns with PowerShell. I'm sure that this was possible back then with just PnP Module. However I'm not sure if you can do this if your "Alex Brown" isn't in your Active Directory anymore.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).